# Shapeshifting an individual's physiology for environment (Space Whale)

Tags: space, shapeshifters, adaptability, mythical-creatures

From popular fiction, I think the idea of a Space Whale fairly well defined. Dozens of kilometres from stem to stern, an ecosystem for many creatures in and of itself, undertaking millennia long migrations from system to system, yada yada - you probably get the picture.

In the course of this this creature's life, it'll encounter incredibly variable conditions (the interstellar void, relatively dense protoplanetary regions, energy-rich expanses over massive stars, the homes of whatever it uses to feed, etc), - and as it goes through different conditions, it'll physiologically shift to adapt to its surroundings. Given how space is a pretty wild place, I'd imagine purely shifting from one predefined state to another probably wouldn't cut it, and some more continual adaptive approach would be needed.

**The question:**

How on a physiological could this creature pull this off?
What would be required for changes within the creature itself to occur in response to unpredicted situations?

Comment: Evolution is not the word you're looking for. Evolution occurs over generations and involves heredity, selection, etc; this is just adaptation.

Comment: What do you mean by "cellular"? Cells as we know them on earth have water in them, which would make existence in space quite difficult. It's difficult to give a reason how such an adaptation could happen if the biology were completely different, like if they weren't carbon-based lifeforms.

Comment: @Fraser [See this Wikipedia page on cellular adaptation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_adaptation)

Comment: If you know it's not evolution, don't use this word and tag.

Comment: @Fraser It's not really fair to edit your question with the aim of negating an existing answer.

Comment: @Pᴇᴛᴇ Sorry if it seems like that, my intent was actually to clarify what the original post said, as it required more detail not to be vague there.

Comment: @Pᴇᴛᴇ I'm somewhat new to these forms, what would the correct way be to make a badly worded question better?

Comment: I changed your title. As @Zxyrra said, it wasn't accurate. Luckily, WB does have a term for this kind of metamorphosis: shapeshifting. I added the shapeshifter tag as well... you may find good info about this topic by looking at other questions under that tag.

Comment: Pictures your average space whale? Ooookey... "Another thing that no one made too much fuss about was the fact that against all probability a sperm whale had suddenly been called into existence some miles above the surface of an alien planet. And since this is not a naturally tenable position for a whale  this innocent creature had very little time to come to terms with its identity as a whale before it had to come to terms with suddenly not being a whale at all. This is what it thought as it fell..."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Space Whales are comprised of Zooids

[Zooids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zooid) are single animals that form part of a larger animal - the larger animal being in effect a colony.

So, your space whale would contain many different kinds of zooids that perform specific functions and have a [particular skill-set](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0936501/).

So, when your whale needs to move, more propulsion zooids are created and deployed.  For feeding, others are created, and so on.  You end up with a dynamic adaptation of the whole animal depend on its needs.

[image]
[Source](http://ocean.si.edu/ocean-photos/jellyfish-or-siphonophore-colony) - Siphonophore zooids forming a jellyfish.

Comment: Well, you've not defined any special needs/abilities.  I assumed the same as for a normal marine whale - moving, feeding, bearing young.  Space whales are improbable enough, there's no reason why these zooids can't also be extraordinary.

Comment: @Fraser What I would have answered, so I'll expand: The zooids are much smaller with much faster rate of evolution. Given the size of the whale evolving in response to external issues should be possible. The whale might even have ability to control the rate of zooids evolution.

Comment: Pete: I suggest you edit the answer to add @VilleNiemi comment to the answer's main body. It's a perfect addition.

Answer (score 4):

What you're talking about isn't evolution.  Evolution, by definition, occurs over an entire species as individuals with a greater capacity to survive are able to reproduce.

An organism could have evolved to adapt to *specific* changes in its environment, provided its ancestors experienced those changes frequently, but they cannot innovate new changes.  Some fish can change from fresh water to salt water physiology, for example, because their ancestors lived in a changing environment where being able to adapt to both environments was beneficial and therefore the ones who had that ability *already* passed it on to their children.  But an individual from such a species cannot spontaneously develop the ability to live in acid if their species has never needed to before.

The only adaptation that is capable of making *new innovations* within a single individual's lifespan is **intelligence** - in fact, this is the whole point of intelligence.  It is thought to be the reason why octopuses, a non-social species, are relatively intelligent - they live in complex, unpredictably changing environments where being able to adapt to new food sources and avoid new predators is important.  (Social animals also often develop intelligence because they live in a complex, changing environment consisting of *other members of their own species*.)

For an organism to physically change its body in response to novel circumstances, it would need to have *conscious control* over almost every aspect of its physiology, from its chemistry to its body structure.

In space, raw materials are rare but (if you're close to a star) energy can be abundant.  It may be worthwhile for a space creature to be intelligent, as it can use sunlight to power its brain, and will need to calculate precise trajectories in order to propel itself to new food sources, which will be used mainly to acquire the mass it needs for reproduction.  It may also cannibalize parts of its own body to acquire precious mass, and could choose to grow new limbs in different ways.  This process *would* use a lot of energy, so it should do so only when it is near a star.